Equivalence between two events regarding Poisson and Exponential distributions.
The number of newspapers someone sells in a minute is a discrete variable $X\sim\text{Po}(5/6)$.
I'm trying to compute the probability of "more than 8 minutes passes till the fifth sale".
Since between sales we have a variable $T\sim \text{Exp}(5/6)$, I defined $T_j':$"time between the $(j-1)$-th sale and the $j$-th sale", $j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, where $T_j'\sim \text{Exp}(5/6)$.
Then $Z=T_1'+T_2'+T_3+T_4'+T_5'$ is $Z\sim\text{Erlang}(5/6,~5)$. I got that $\mathbb{P}(Z>8)=0.205$.
However, when I first got into this exercise, I couldn't use Erlang distribution, this is meant to be done with Poisson and Exponential distributions. One way to solve it is the following one, which I don't fully understand:
Let $X_8$:"amount of sales in 8 minutes", where $X_8\sim\text{Po}(5/6\cdot 8)=\text{Po}(20/3)$ and $T_5$:"time till the fifth sale". What we want is $\mathbb{P}(T_5>8)$. Then, using the equivalence of events: $T_5>8\iff \color{red}{X_8<5}$, we get that $$\mathbb{P}(T_5>8)=\mathbb{P}(X_8\leq 4)=0.205,$$
which led to the same result. But why are those events equivalent? When I try to think about it, I feel that $T_5>8\iff \color{red}{X_8=4}$, and not $X_8<5$ (which is the same as $X_8\leq 4$), since we need $4$ sales in 8 minutes, and then the fifth one. But if I compute that, I don't get $0.205.$

Suppose zero sales happen in the first eight minutes. This means ${X_8=4}$ did not occur (because $X_4=0$), but ${T_5>8}$ did occur (whenever the fifth sale happens, it must certainly be more than eight minutes after the start). Since it is possible for ${T_5>8}$ to occur, while ${X_8=4}$ does not occur, you cannot say that $T_5>8\iff X_8=4$. Does that make sense?

It is starting to make sense.  I understand that $\iff$ with ${X_8=4}$ is false, but why the $\leq$ goes there?

There should be
$$
Z = T_1 + T_2 +T_3 +T_4 +T_5 > 8 \Longleftrightarrow X_8 < 5, 
$$
because both events represent "more than 8 minutes passes till the fifth sale",
instead of
$$
T_5 > 8
$$
which only represents the duration between 4th and 5th sales.

Just in case, in the second part of my question, $T_5$ is not the same as the first $T_5$. The former is what you say (time between the fourth and the fifth sale) and the latter is time till the fifth sale. I'm gonna change the letter in case it confuses someone else.
